# Visual Basic Highlights the label

Tags: vb6

Im a Visual Basic 6.0 programmer i want to know if it possible to make highlights in Label if it mouse pointed or mouse over in label and the highlights will remove if not mouse pointed or mouse over in label??

Comment: The answer is probably yes.

Comment: Please do not misuse the tags field.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ToolTipText` property to the text you want to display when you hover.  I believe that is what you're after :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MouseMove event of the label to highlight it, and the MouseMove event of the surrounding area (for example the form itself) to remove the highlight.

```
'1 form with
'  1 label: name=Label1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  HighlightLabel False
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  HighlightLabel True
End Sub

Private Sub HighlightLabel(blnHighlight As Boolean)
  Label1.FontBold = blnHighlight
  Label1.FontItalic = blnHighlight
End Sub
```

Comment: Half the answer. You also need to set them back to False when the mouse *leaves* the control.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I missed that part. I changed my answer.